# foreach - proper row and col to display data

Tags: javascript, foreach, row, bootstrapping, col

I am trying to display data from db and below is the image how the data should be displayed.

[image]

It can be done with the following codes.

```
  <div class="row>

  </div>
  <div class="row>
       <div class="col-lg-3></div>
       <div class="col-lg-3></div>
       <div class="col-lg-3></div>
       <div class="col-lg-3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row>
       <div class="col-lg-4></div>
       <div class="col-lg-4></div>
       <div class="col-lg-4></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row>
       <div class="col-lg-6></div>
       <div class="col-lg-6></div>
  </div>
```

But I'm having difficulty doing this inside `foreach` loop.

```
   $stm = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE id = :id"); 
   $stm->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stm->execute();
   $data = $stm->fetchAll();


          <?php foreach($data as $row) : ?>
                  //waaahhhhhhhh

          <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can someone give me an idea how will I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work :

```
<?php $index = 0 ?>
<?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
    <div class="row>
      <?php if($index === 0): ?>
        <?= $row['property'] ?>
      <?php elseif($index >= 1 && $index <= 4): ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3>
          <?= $row['property'] ?>
        </div>
      <?php elseif($index >= 5 && $index <= 7): ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4>
          <?= $row['property'] ?>
        </div>
      <?php else: ?>
        <div class="col-lg-6>
          <?= $row['property'] ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php $index++ ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```